# java escape parenthesis

Tags: java, regex, escaping, parentheses

i have this little class to make a multiple replace on a string:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
public class MultipleReplace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> tokens = new HashMap<String,String>();
        tokens.put(":asd:", "<img src=asd.gif>");
        tokens.put(":)", "<img src=sorriso.gif>");
        String template = ":asd: bravo! :)";
        String patternString = "(" + StringUtils.join(tokens.keySet(), "|") + ")";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(template);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(matcher.find()) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, tokens.get(matcher.group(1)));
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

The problem is on the second replace, where i have a parenthesis that result in:

**Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 8
(:)|:asd:)**

How i can escape the parenthesis? 
Or, can you suggest an alternative to do this multiple replace?

Thank you very much and sorry for my english :)

**EDIT:**

Escaping with backslash ')' doesn't work too, it won't compile:

**"Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ )"**

**NEW EDIT**

using two backslashes compile, but doesn't do the replacement.

**LAST EDIT**

Finally found the solution, using Pattern.quote while building the pattern. Have to use an iterator to do the loop.

Here the correct code:

```
package string;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class MultipleReplace {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> tokens = new HashMap<String,String>();
        tokens.put(":asd:", "<img src=asd.gif>");
        tokens.put(":)", "<img src=sorriso.gif>");
        String template = ":asd: bravo! :)";
        Iterator it = tokens.entrySet().iterator();
        String patternString = "(";
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
            patternString = patternString +Pattern.quote((String) pairs.getKey());
            if (it.hasNext())
            {
                patternString = patternString + "|";
            }
        }
        patternString = patternString + ")";
        System.out.println(patternString);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(template);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while(matcher.find()) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, tokens.get(matcher.group(1)));
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Please comment on it if i can improve the work! Thank you very much!

Comment: Your replacing is in general OK, but you can run into problems when your to-be-replaced tokens are not fixed. Consider using `tokens.put(Pattern.quote(original), replacement)`. Btw., you need no group, use `matcher.group(0)`.

Comment: When you use `Pattern.quote` you need not and must not escape the parens. So this is another solution.

Comment: How could I do this with an uncompiled regex (String.matching())?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `Pattern.quote` like I wrote in the comment. It works with every string and for long Strings containing a lot of non alphanumerical chars it's less error-prone.

### Update

This is a shiny (and untested) Java 8 solution:

```
    final Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>();
    tokens.put(":asd:", "<img src=asd.gif>");
    tokens.put(":)", "<img src=sorriso.gif>");
    final String template = ":asd: bravo! :)";

    final String patternString = tokens.keySet()
        .stream().map(Pattern::quote).collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(template);
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, tokens.get(matcher.group(0)));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: thank you, can you provide an example: i'm trying this: tokens.put(Pattern.quote(":)"), "<img src=/faccine/sorrisone.gif>");
  String template = ":asd: bravo! :)";

Comment: but i have a NullPointerException

Comment: SORRY. You must put the original String in the Map in order to find the match. Use the quoted String in the pattern only.

Comment: This applies to every solution. No matter how you create the pattern for matching a String literally, you must put the original String as key in the Map.

Comment: ok, now if i use Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.LITERAL); without escaping, i don't have errors, but it doesn't do the replacements... Thank you very much for your help @maartinus! :)

Comment: Oh... SORRY again... you can't use my "best" solution... even the `|` joining the Strings gets quoted!

Comment: I'd better go to bed. Just one more try: `tokens.put(original, replacement)` without quoting. Use quoting while building the pattern only. This means you can't use `join` and need a loop instead.

Comment: yes!! it works :) I just updated my first post with the correct code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

Use a backslash: `\)`. Parens must be escaped because they can be used to group parts of the regex.

```
    String template = ":asd: bravo\\! :\\)";
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it won't compile: "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"

Comment: @Laphroaig: Ah! Put two backslashes.

Comment: Use two of them! Two backslashes in Java source mean one backslash in String, which is what you need.

Comment: using two backslashes compile, but doesn't do the replacement.

Comment: It must work. There must be something else wrong. Forget it and switch to `Pattern.quote` in case you're looking for an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a better example than Tim N.

Let's say you have a String word.

```
word = "http://www.randomwebsite.com/images/That Image (English)";
```

If you want to replace brackets with spaces, simply do:

```
word.replaceAll("\\(", " ");
```

You have to do 2 double back slashes to get the compiler to shut up and not whine.

Also keep in mind, that function returns a String.  So you'd do

```
word = word.replaceAll("\\(", " ");
```

Unless you want to see it, just print it out.